# jQuery AJAX method returns current page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation

First, let me say that I've looked through other similar questions on this site *and* the jQuery documentation.  So far I haven't found something that fixes my issue.

I'm trying to setup a login form for logging in using an email address and password.  I have a PHP-only solution that works just fine, but I'm trying to add AJAX functionality as well.

The code I'm using now returns the whole page that's making the AJAX call.  Just for some extra info, I'm using jQuery 1.10.2 and PHP 5.4.12.  This is also my first time setting up a site to use a PHP script for deciding what other scripts to use based on what data is sent to it, so please bear with me.

Here's my form:

```
<form id="employee_login" name="employee_login" action="portal.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <button id="login" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="error_box">
    <?php if(isset($GLOBALS['loginError']) && $GLOBALS['loginError'] != '') { ?>
        <p class="error"><?php echo $GLOBALS['loginError']; ?></p>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Here's my AJAX function:

```
function ajaxValidate(email, pass, error) {
    if($(email).val() == '' || $(pass).val() == '') {
        $(error).html('<p class="error">You must enter your email address and password!</p>');
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/php-modules/ajax_filter.php',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: { emailAddr: $(email).val(), password: $(pass).val()},
            success: function(text, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                console.log(Date() + ': ' + text);
                try{
                    if( IsType(text, 'json') ) {
                        var ajaxData = $.parseJSON(text);
                        if(ajaxData['error'] != null && ajaxData['error'] != 'undefined')
                            $(error).html('<p class="error">' + ajaxData['error'] + '</p>');
                        else if(ajaxData['is_email'] != 1)
                            $(error).html('<p class="error">You must enter a <strong>VALID</strong> email address.</p>');
                        else if(ajaxData['is_email'] == 1)
                            document.location = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Location');
                        else
                            $(error).html('<p class="error">You must enter your email address and password!</p>');
                    }
                    else if( IsType(text, 'html') ) $(error).html( $.parseHTML(text) );
                    else if( IsType(text, 'xml') ) alert('Data is XML.');
                }
                catch(e) {
                    $(error).html('<p class="error">' + e.description + '</p>');
                    console.debug(e);
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                $(error).html('<p class="error">' + jqXHR.status + ' ' + errorThrown + ' ' + jqXHR.responseText + '</p>');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The script I'm sending the AJAX call to is only setup for 1 request so far.  I intend to add more later.  I'm not sure if I've setup too many checks either, but I wanted to be safe since I'm not very familiar with something like this.  And the "unidentified error" thing I added just today was a replacement for a "return false" that I thought *could've* been causing the problem.  Here's the code:

```
<?php
// a filter for all AJAX requests

// for email checking
if( isset($_POST['emailAddr']) ) {
    require_once('login.php');
    if(isset($GLOBALS['loginError']) && $GLOBALS['loginError'] != '') {
        echo '{"error":"' . $GLOBALS['loginError'] . '"}';
    } else echo '{"error":"Unidentified error"}';
}
// if $_POST isn't set, isn't an array, or has a length less than 1, return an error
else if(!isset($_POST) || !is_array($_POST) || count($_POST) < 1) {
    echo '{"error":"No data sent"}';
}
// if the previous check fails, invalid or insuficient data was sent
else {
    echo '{"error":"Could not process request"}';
}
?>
```

The last piece is my login checking script.  I've omitted the actual query and table fields because those parts work fine when using my PHP-only solution.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

// halt execution if the login fields are empty
if((!isset($_POST['emailAddr']) || $_POST['emailAddr'] == "") && (!isset($_POST['password']) || $_POST['password'] == "")) {
    $GLOBALS['loginError'] =  'You must enter your email and password!';
}
else {// check for valid email
    require_once('is_email.php');
    if( !is_email($_POST['emailAddr']) ) $GLOBALS['loginError'] = 'You must enter a valid email address!';
    else if($_POST['emailAddr'] != "" && $_POST['password'] != "") {
        try{
            // PDO setup
            include('pdo.php');
            $con = createPDO();

            // PDO statement preparation and execution
            $query = $con->prepare("[query code];");
            $email = $_POST['emailAddr'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            // returned PDO query data
            if($query->execute( array($email) ) ) {
                while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    if(strtolower($email) == strtolower($row['email']) && $password == $row['password']) {
                        // set session data
                        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['[id field]'];
                        $_SESSION['name'] = ucfirst($row['[name field]']);
                        $_SESSION['email'] = $row['[email field]'];
                        session_regenerate_id();
                        header("location: /");
                    }
                    else $GLOBALS['loginError'] = 'ID or password incorrect!';
                }
            }
            } catch(Exception $e) { 
                $GLOBALS['loginError'] = $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
        else $GLOBALS['loginError'] = 'You must enter your email and password!';
    }
}
?>
```

I've cut out an unnecessary function and `return false;` lines, added the `console.log();` method, changed the `email:` value name in the ajax `data:` option to `emailAddr:` (in my PHP code too) in case of a name conflict between it and my `email` variable, and changed my code to parse for HTML in case of PHP generating HTML error messages.  My parentheses, braces, and brackets seem to be matched ok (I checked using Sublime Text's parenthesis/brace/bracket highlighting to check), the form checking portion of the script works fine.

I'm honestly at a loss...

Also, thanks to everyone who reads through this long-winded post.

**Question updates**:

I just realized that parsing code in the `try` is working correctly.  Since the `$.parseJSON` doesn't work, it's skipping down to the if statement for parsing HTML and that one is working.

**Code changes**:

I replaced some `return` statements with `echo`, per *Morganster*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed.  Someone named [Scott Sawyer](https://plus.google.com/106628015809565209769) said `header("Location: /")` would cause the `$.ajax()` method to return the whole current page.  The redirect seems to be working now.  Thanks for the input everyone.

Answer (score 0):

When you are going to return data across an ajax call, you must print your data.

For example,

```
$var['error']="Could not process request";

echo json_encode($var);
```

Comment: My friend said that `return` does the same thing in AJAX calls.  I didn't edit my answer again though.  I'll just leave it alone for now until I get some more input.

Comment: Are you preventing the default behavior of the submit button ?

Comment: Yes.  All the things I read about intercepting the form's submit event didn't work, but I did come across something that said setting the button's type to *button* would keep the form from submitting.  I'm doing this using JS so that if the user turns JS off the form will submit and use the PHP solution I setup first.